# can't get data from mongodb atlas in mere app

Tags: mongodb, mern

so I am trying to connect to mongodb and see if it can find a user and it keeps saying null in insomnia but the user is there I added it in mondo compass and its showing in my collection and the server is working fine

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/027Rb.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kd03q.png)[[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZ6Uk.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAHGU.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dg2H2.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EiKvt.png)

I tried making a new user and even changing the port but nothing is working and I am not sure why

Comment: Please don't use images for code/errors/text/tracebacks/etc. - just include them in a code block.

Comment: Should your request document have `"username": "john"` instead of `"username": "jogn"`?

Comment: @rickhg12hs I tried fixing that still nothing

Comment: I'm only familiar with the _"M"_ in _"MERN"_, and I'm wondering how the `recipes` database is specified in the code.  Is your code accessing the correct database?

Comment: @rickhg12hs I am following a video online and doing exactly what he is doing and I did connect from mongodb using the link in the database and I added my password where its specified in the link

Comment: If you change your connection string to `... .mongodb.net/recipes ...`, i.e., include the database in the connection string, does it work differently?

Answer (score 1):

changed my connection string to ... .mongodb.net/recipes ..., i.e., include the database in the connection string and it works now